# Get / calculate external MSDN url for .NET type with generic arguments

Tags: c#, .net, types, msdn

The external MSDN documentation page for types that have NO generic arguments can be accessed by using the following link format (e.g. [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/**< ISO_LANGUAGE >**/library/**< FULL_TYPE_NAME >**.aspx

But types, like generic [List< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) are accessed via something that is similar to a hash:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/**6sh2ey19**.aspx

How does Microsoft calculates that "hash" *6sh2ey19* or where is it stored?

Is there a solution for C#, e.g.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN provides a set of web services that will let you determine the URL and even display the content if you so wish:

http://services.msdn.microsoft.com/ContentServices/ContentService.asmx

There is also a decent article from the MSDN magazine on how to consume the web services, which might be a good starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163541.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I created a console application to download the full list of BCL classes from MSDN ContentService suggested by John Koerner. The result is a CSV file with two columns (type name, content id) which can be used to create direct MSDN links.

CSV file for .NET Framework 4.5 can be downloaded here (~165 kbytes):
https://github.com/yallie/MsdnHelper/blob/master/out/ClassLibrary45.csv.gz

Here is a C# snippet how to load the CSV into IDictionary<string, string>:
https://github.com/yallie/MsdnHelper/blob/master/out/ClassLibrary45.cs

Creating MSDN links using this dictionary:

```
var contentId = classes["System.IDisposable"]; // full type name
var msdnLink = string.Format("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/{0}.aspx", contentId);
```